# why my app closes like going to background mode when Multiple clicks on Textview/Views?

Tags: java, android

i have a `TextView` or `Button` when i click on any `View` or `TextView` android app getting closed like entered into background mode. why this is happened i don't know. 
please help me out of this bug.
Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/text_cta"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_all"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_regular"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="@color/colorOrange"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_20" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is My click actions:

```
@OnClick({R.id.ll_profile, R.id.tv_all})
    public void onViewClicked(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.ll_profile:
                //callProfileAPI();
                startActivity(new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class).putExtra("isFrom", ""));
                break;
             case R.id.tv_all:
                startActivity(new Intent(context, ViewAllClubNewsActivity.class).putExtra("isFrom", "Home"));
                break;
     }
}
```

i'm really annoying for this error, i don't find any answers for this. 
i tried with below line added in my view:

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
```

but i doesn't event work.

below is the stack trace coming everytime:
    **06-09 12:06:49.403 7048-8137/com.bocawestcc.cobaltmemberapp E/FA: Unable to use remote or local measurement implementation. Please register the AppMeasurementService service in the app manifest**

Please help me...

Comment: Where is the stack Trace ?

Comment: app not getting crashed, it's just closed and goes to background so there no stack trace

Comment: Most probably it crashes on the `next activity` ...there must be some stack Trace ..

Comment: No dude it's not getting crashed, i'm sure it's just closed the current activity and goes to background.when i open application it's opened from our navigated activity(like next activity).

Comment: @Santanu Sur look at my question i added stack trace, which is not related to this bug i hope.